# How to deploy a Flask application with Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, virtualenv, gunicorn

Ok, I'm new to Python/Flask deployment and was following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial.

This is my system file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myapp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=deployer
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/deployer/myapp
Environment="PATH=/home/deployer/myapp/myapp_env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/deployer/myapp/myapp_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myapp.sock -m 007 appserver:gunicorn_app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it doesn't work. I get `Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC` or `/root/myapp/myapp_env/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied`

If I `cd` into my myapp directory and issue the gunicorn command like so:

```
gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:smarrttrader_api.sock -m 007 appserver:gunicorn_app
```

Everything works fine. If I do a which gunicorn from my app directory I get `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn` and try to run ()from elsewhere in the server like so:

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:smarrttrader_api.sock -m 007 appserver:gunicorn_app
```

It doesn't work and I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'appserver'`, so how can I get it to work?

Comment: Do you have the virtualenv activated when runing your gunicorn by hand ? it looks like you have permission probleme and you are not running the same gunicorn exec by hand and in your service

Comment: No, I have purposefully deactivated my virtualenv. And yes, I suspect the same issue but I do not know how to resolve.

Comment: seems like you have two instances of gunicorn, one from a binary package (pointing to /usr/local/bin/gunicor), and another as a python package. first get rid of the binary package. Also, why are you getting `/root/myapp/myapp_env/bin/python3`, where's the root directory coming from, the whole setup should run as 'deployer' user, what's in /root?